# EM propagation in solids

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, refraction

I am interested to understand how EM waves (especially the ones in the microwave range) propagate though solids. I understand that the refractive index can be used to determine whether the wave is refracted or reflected is that correct? What about absorption?
What about polarization, how does it came in to play?
I understand it is probably a big topic. If you can provide a good resource (book, website) to approach the topic or make a list of the concepts needed to address the topic would be a good start. The final goal would be a better understanding of multipath effect in GPS, but I am interested also on a theoretical level.

Comment: Refraction and reflection aren't really relevant to *propagation*. I assume, you are interested in the behavior of an EM wave as it approaches an interface? As far as GPS is concerned, I guess you want to know not so much about propagation in solids, but, rather, in the atmosphere; am I correct? The refractive index can be used to determine absorption too, it is, in general, a complex value and the imaginary part determines the absorption.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP yes i am interested also in the behavior of an EM wave as it approaches an interface.  I would like also to understand about an EM wave that partially pass trough an obstacle and partially is reflected by it. How i can i know how will it behave given an EM wave (frequency, direction of propagation and polarization) and a certain object (geometry and material properties).